# SQL -- SUM query not returning 0s (MS-Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum

I am trying to do a SQL sum query in Access, but it only returns non-zero answers. I want to also see the sums that are 0. In the data, the records are indeed 0, not nulls.

Fields in the table include county codes (county_code), pounds of chemicals applied (lbs_chem), and the chemical code (chem_code). Each record is a single application of chemicals in that county. I want to sum up how many pounds of a specific chemical were applied in each county. I want my results to show 0 if 0 pounds were applied. Instead, my results simply skip the counties with 0 pounds.

```
SELECT county_code, sum(lbs_chem)
FROM chem_apps_1991
WHERE chem_code="465"
GROUP BY county_code
ORDER BY county_code
```

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see all the counties, then don't filter them out.  Use conditional aggregation instead of a `where` clause:

```
SELECT county_code,
      sum(iif(chem_code = "465", lbs_chem, 0))
FROM chem_apps_1991
GROUP BY county_code
ORDER BY county_code;
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I'm relatively new to SQL so conditional aggregation is new to me.